# What is the history of the Deathly Hallows?

Tags: harry-potter

In Harry potter, there are three Deathly Hallows, The Elder wand, Invisibility cloak and Resurrection stone. Now we know the story behind that, how the three Peverell brothers got them from Death itself.

[This](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/12454/how-could-dumbledore-ever-become-the-owner-of-the-elder-wand) thread puts light on the history of the Elder wand and we know the end of it too, that it was destroyed by Harry.

But my question relates to the other two. How did the resurrection stone make its way to Dumbeldore and as it was given to Harry in that golden ball, what happened after harry put it on the ground before he was knocked out by "you-know-who".

And the invisibility cloak was the same harry used throughout the series, right? Who gave that to harry, Dumbeldore must be, right? How was that acquired by Dumbeldore?

Answer (score 11):

The Resurrection stone was passed down the Gaunt family line - Voldemort's mother was a Gaunt - and at some point used as the stone in the Gaunt family ring. The ring was one of the items Voldemort turned into a Horcrux, though there's no indication he had any idea what the stone actually was. It was found by Dumbledore in the Gaunt's abandoned shack - hidden and concealed by Voldemort - during the summer between Harry's fifth and sixth years at Hogwarts.

The Invisibility Cloak was passed down the Potter family line. Dumbledore asked to borrow the cloak from James Potter (Harry's father) shortly before his death, but he was actually examining it to determine if it was in fact one of the three Hallows. He returned it to Harry on Christmas day during his first year at Hogwarts.

Answer (score 7):

So the the other Hallows are told to have been items passed down.  This was communicated in both movies and the book series.  The Invisibility cloak was passed down generation to generation in Harry's family.  Before his father died he asked Dumbledore to hold on the cloak for Harry.

As for the resurrection stone it was actually merged into a ring that Dumbledore found, during his search for Voldemort's horcrux. Dumbledore then inserted it into the golden snitch and left it for Harry upon his death.

I don't currently have the books available to  specify whose family line the ring came down but I believe it had something to do with the Riddle family.

Comment: Voldemort's father was a muggle so it did not pass down that line. It was his mother's heritage. And Dumbledore borrowed the cloak from Harry's father and was in it's possession at the time of Harry's father's death. Thus he gave it back to Harry as would be the ethical thing to do.

Comment: @Selenog Voldemort wasn't pure-blooded? O.O - I missed that.